# Gmaps4rails + Infobox : Remote links fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

Each marker on my map has an infowindow.

If I use the Infobox plugin to build the infowindow, remote links inside it process action as "HTML" instead of "JS".

I should precise that everything work well (I mean, action processed as "JS") when I remove the infoboxBuilder.

My code :

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });

# In the Infowindow : <%= link_to "More", voir_infos_path(t), :remote => true %>
# Log : Started GET "/voir_infos/545e1dd382cd47db98000bb9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-04 23:10:56 +0100
Processing by ObjetsController#voir_infos as HTML
```

But when I remove the InfoBoxBuilder :

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
# Same code in Infowindow : <%= link_to "More", voir_infos_path(t), :remote => true %>
# Log : Started GET "/voir_infos/545e23ae82cd47e5ac000542" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-04 23:13:53 +0100
Processing by ObjetsController#voir_infos as JS
```

Here the `infoboxbuilder.js.coffee` I found on stackoverflow :

```
class @InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker # inherit from base builder
# override method
create_infowindow: ->
   return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow

boxText = document.createElement("div")
boxText.setAttribute("class", 'yellow') #to customize
boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
@infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

@bind_infowindow() 

infobox: (boxText)->
  content: boxText
  boxClass: "infoBox box-shadow"
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -380)
  closeBoxURL: ""
  boxStyle:
    width: "280px"
```

How could I make it work ?
Thanks

EDIT

I have this link in each Infowindow : `<%= link_to "More", voir_infos_path(t), :remote => true %>` which should process ObjetsController#voir_infos as "JS", isn't it ?

When I use the Infobox plugin to display the infowindow (with this part of code : `builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder}`  and click on "More", `:remote => true` doesn't work, and ObjetsController#voir_infos is processed as "HTML" instead as "JS".

When I remove `builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder}`, everything work well, and when I click on "More", ObjetsController#voir_infos is processed as "JS".

EDIT 2 :

The HTML generated for the Infowindow :

```
<div class="infoBox box-shadow" style="width: 280px; position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 132.270229334012px; top: 72.179231562186px; cursor: default;"><div class="yellow"><div class="row iw-content">
<div>
    <img src="/covers/max_creer/missing.png">
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h6> Maison Bloc </h6>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <a href="/voir_infos/545e1de582cd47db98000d91"  data-remote="true">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant understand, sorry

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be more explicit in my Edit. Please tell me if it's better.

Comment: this seems crazy, is it possible for you to check the html generated in the infowindow (with your browser inspect tool)

Comment: I think I understand: infobox must not be reachable by rails js listeners, so it behaves as a standard link => html

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help; I'm going to use jQuery Ajax.

Comment: or trigger https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L93 when link is clicked... js in infowindows can be tricky